# @TestPropertySource is not loading properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

I'm writing integration test for my spring boot application but when I try to override some properties using @TestPropertySource, it's loading the property file defined in the context xml but it's not overriding the properties defined in the annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {DefaultApp.class, MessageITCase.Config.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.profiles.active=hornetq", "test.url=http://www.test.com/",
                    "test.api.key=343krqmekrfdaskfnajk"})
public class MessageITCase {
    @Value("${test.url}")
    private String testUrl;

    @Value("${test.api.key}")
    private String testApiKey;

    @Test
    public void testUrl() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loaded test url:" + testUrl);
    }



    @Configuration
    @ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/test-context.xml")
    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this problem? inline properties through TestPropertySource do not seem to be working for me either.

Comment: Not yet, but I've changed my configuration so that I'm using `@IntegrationTest` annotation instead of `@TestPropertySource`. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this feature with Spring Boot 1.4
Line below works pretty well

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "key=value", "eureka.client.enabled=false" })
```

Nevertheless new @SpringBootTest annotation is working as well

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = { "key=value", "eureka.client.enabled=false" }
)
public class NewBootTest {

    @Value("${key}")
    public String key;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("great " + key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by updating the Spring Context beans.xml to use
`org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

From the JavaDoc of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

> Deprecated.
> as of 5.2; use [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) instead which is more flexible through taking advantage of the [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) and [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) mechanisms.