# TestNG test not using TestPropertySource for injecting @Value

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, testng

I'm trying to write tests for a class that has a field value injected from a properties file. I'm trying to utilize the `TestPropertySource` annotation to get values in there while running TestNG tests, but it seems to be ignoring my properties file.

There's dozens of similar questions, which I tried to carefully read and try their implementations where possible. It seems my question is yet slightly different though, here's why:

- "[**@TestPropertSource and @PropertySource don't work for JUnit**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32633638/419956)": talks about JUnit instead of TestNG (might or might not be relevant?) and it also talks about injecting a property value into a field on the *test* class (as opposed to the unit under test).
- "[**@TestPropertySource not working?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40534724/419956)": talks about how to ignore missing properties, not how to fix it.
- "[**@TestPropertySource is not loading properties**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33371875/419956)": also talks about injecting values in to test class fields (did try `@RunWith` or `@SpringBootTest` but that didn't help either).
- The other links in [Google search results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=TestPropertySource%20not%20working) also didn't help.

What do you need to do to get a unit-under-test with `@Value` annotated fields set with their property? Can I somehow request spring to provide me with instances of my class instead of `new`ing them myself?

Here's a minimal repro.

**Foo.java**

```
package nl.jeroenheijmans.stackoverflow.testngprops;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Foo {
    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private String myProp;

    public String ExposeProp() {
        return myProp;
    }
}
```

**FooTest.java**

```
package nl.jeroenheijmans.stackoverflow.testngprops;

import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void sanityCheck(){
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Assert.assertNotNull(foo); // Success!
    }

    @Test
    public void testProperty() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Assert.assertEquals(foo.ExposeProp(), "checkcheck"); // Fail!
    }
}
```

**application.properties (in both the `main` and `test` folder)**

```
my.prop=checkcheck
```

**Main.java**

```
package nl.jeroenheijmans.stackoverflow.testngprops;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.jeroenheijmans.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>testngprops</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>${testng.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.5</maven.compiler.version>
        <org.springframework.boot.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved this.

In a nutshell, I believe you were missing the part of extending `org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and using Dependency Injection for the object `Foo` via the `@Autowire` annotation. Since you were instantiating the `Foo` object, the values weren't being injected into it, which explains why the assertions were failing.

**Main.java**

```
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn45716815;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }
}
```

The reason for using `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})` can be found in this thread : [Mongo tries to connect automatically to port 27017(localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414367/mongo-tries-to-connect-automatically-to-port-27017localhost)

**Update:** *Exclusion of Mongo configuration is optional and you don't need to be doing this, if you have a project which is properly setup for Mongo.*

Here's how the **FooTest.java** looks like

```
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn45716815;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void sanityCheck() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(foo);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProperty() {
        Assert.assertEquals(foo.ExposeProp(), "checkcheck");
    }
}
```

Here's how my maven dependencies looks like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The reason for adding an exclusion to spring-boot-starter-logging can be found here : [Disable Logback in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot)

**Update:** *Exclusion of logback is optional and you don't need to be doing this, if you have a project which is properly setup for working with logback.*

Here's the output when I ran this test :

```
objc[36167]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1026784c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1027404e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, gonna check it out in a bit. (I'm baffled by the way that Mongo pops up, hadn't realized that there's mongo-related dependencies in the chain somewhere.)

Comment: The `@SpringBootTest` + `...extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` + `@AutoWired` property did the trick. The Mongo stuff, the Logback stuff, and the Log4j stuff weren't needed to get my tests passing though.

Comment: In any case: thank you for your insights! I'll certainly remember to accept the answer if this ends up being my final solution (though see my previous comment, the mongo/logging stuff seems immaterial?). One thing I'm not certain about is that this all implies that I'm running integration tests instead of unit tests, need to think about that a wee bit to see if there is (or I should) take another approach. - Again though: thanks for your excellent help!

Comment: @Jeroen - I had included everything that I followed to get this solution to work and in that haste, I forgot to call out steps which were supposed to be optional. The Mongo config exclusion wouldnt be required if your project is properly configured to use one (in my case, i was just working with an example project) and the same goes for logback as well. I have updated my answer to explicitly call these two steps out as optional steps.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for clarifying. I'm still learning with spring-boot so it's helpful to know why each change would(n't) be needed.

Comment: @Jeroen - I dont know spring.. which explains why I ended up putting everything that I did, in the answer :)