# @TestPropertySource - Values not set / set as null from test properties file

Tags: java, spring, junit, null, properties-file

My Junit is not picking up properties set in test properties file.
I get no error, but value returned from properties file is null

**CLASS TO BE TESTED:**

```
package com.abc.mysource.mypackage;

@Component
@ComponentScan
public class MyHelper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("commonProperties")
    private CommonProperties commonProperties;  

    public LocalDateTime method1ThatUsesCommonProperties(LocalDateTime startDateTime) throws Exception {
        String customUserType = commonProperties.getUserType(); // Returns null if run as JUnit test
        //Further processing
    }
}
```

**SUPPORTING COMPONENTS - BEANS & CONFIG CLASSES:**

```
package com.abc.mysource.mypackage;
@Component
public class CommonProperties {
     @Value("${myhelper.userType}")
     private String userType;

         public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }
    public void setCalendarType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
}
```

**CONFIG CLASS:**

```
package com.abc.mysource.mypackage;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.abc.mysource.mypackage.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
public class CommonConfig {}
```

**default.properties under src/main/resources**

```
myhelper.userType=PRIORITY
```

**MY TEST CLASS:**

```
package com.abc.mysource.mypackage.test;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyHelper.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:default-test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyHelperTest {
    @MockBean(name="commonProperties")
    private CommonProperties commonProperties;

    @Autowired
    private MyHelper myHelper;

    @Test
    public void testMethod1ThatUsesCommonProperties() {
        myHelper.method1ThatUsesCommonProperties();
    }
}
```

**default-test.properties defined under /src/test/resources:**

```
myhelper.userType=COMMON
```

**NOTE:**

I moved default-test.properties to /src/main/resources - commonProperties.getUserType() is null

I even used @TestPropertySource(properties = {"myhelper.userType=COMMON"}). Same result

**NOTE 2:**

I tried the solution on [@TestPropertySource is not loading properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371875/testpropertysource-is-not-loading-properties).

This solution requires me to create a duplicate bean called CommonProperties under src/test/java. But @MockBean fails when I do

```
@MockBean(name="commonProperties")
private CommonProperties commonProperties;
```

Please do not mark a duplicate.

**NOTE 3:**
Mine is a spring, not a spring boot application.

Comment: Your question helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MockBeans are suited if you don't need specific state. Usually this bean is "isolated" and every method call of this bean will have the same result. It is "isolated" -> the service that uses @Value annotation will not apply on this bean.

What you need is a "normal" bean, properly constructed and initialized. Please use @Autowired annotation and define another bean if needed, using a test profile.

Comment: Changing MockBean -> Autowired fixed this issue.